# Dark spots on cactus?

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

My elderly relative has asked me to do a research on her cactus which has recently got these dark spots:

[image]

I poked them and they are dry and hard when you touch them. There is no liquid or mush. They are only present on the spots the needles come from. Otherwise the cactus is looking healthy and it’s constantly growing.

I don’t know what kind of cactus is this. I bought it for her at local grocery store 4 years ago.

Should I “amputate” these spots?

Comment: Can't view the image. Your description sounds interesting. The spots where the needles come from are called areoles. They are also where flowers and new growth comes from.

Comment: https://scontent.fiev12-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/fr/cp0/e15/q65/38764073_1373473019453066_7285179568208478208_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&oh=13cd9253e057e4033579e4f1db60183e&oe=5C0A491E I have re-uploaded it, could you please take a look?

Comment: Very interesting. I've never seen anything like that. Do the dots go all the way around or are they just on one side? One other possibly related item; does the pot have drainage holes in the bottom? It looks like a glazed ceramic pot. Other than the dots, it doesn't look bad.

Comment: Are the black parts fuzzy or slightly furry looking when you look closely? - you might need a magnifying glass. I can't magnify the photo sufficiently well to tell... and can you add a photo that shows the top of the cactus too, for ID purposes please.